# No such file or directory in VScode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, visual-studio-code

Does anyone has a solution for this error?´

```
dan@LAPTOP-U61VD2F3:/mnt/c/Users/danyl/Desktop/New folder$ ruby "c:\Users\danyl\Desktop\New folder\Lesson.rb"     
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby: No such file or directory -- c:\\Users\\danyl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Lesson.rb (LoadError)
dan@LAPTOP-U61VD2F3:/mnt/c/Users/danyl/Desktop/New folder$
```

Comment: Try to rename 'New folder' without a space and make sure that a file named Lesson.rb is inside 'New folder'

Comment: Giuseppe thanks for answering, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't say "it didn't work." Please explain yourself by saying "When I did x I got y. I previously got z and was expecting to get n." Phrases like "it didn't work" are filler that do not provide diagnostically useful information.

Comment: anothermh Thanks for you answer too, but there's not much to explain, I fallow the advice and the result from the diagnostic analysis was the same "it didn't work" 

Comment: Giuseppe asked you to do two things -- plural. You responded by saying "it didn't work" -- singular. You might mean many different things: removing the space and retrying reported the same error; removing the space and retrying reported a different error; adding the file and retrying reported the same error; adding the file and retrying reported a different error ... There isn't enough space here to give all the possible outcomes. Don't make the people you are asking for help guess what you mean. **Be explicit**. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.

Comment: anthermh, Again thanks for you explicit answer, and feel free to add a solution to the error if you have one, Thanks for you time! 

Answer (score 2):

Solution in this case:

Go to your settings.json file in Vscode and add this line into the settings:

"code-runner.terminalRoot": "/mnt/",

or you can open settings and find Code-runner: Terminal Root and type this:

/mnt/

Note: For Windows system, replaces the Windows style drive letter in the command with a Unix style root when using a custom shell as the terminal, like Bash or Cgywin. Example: Setting this to '/mnt/' will replace 'C:\path' with '/mnt/c/path'

Answer (score 0):

Solution in this case:

Go to your settings.json file in Vscode and add this line into the settings:

"code-runner.terminalRoot": "/",

or you can open settings and find Code-runner: Terminal Root and type this:

/